# Multiple Joins Mysql Doubles SUM values

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, sum

Im trying to make a a query, but its doubling the Sum values

```
SELECT
cidades.id AS id,
cidades.name AS municipio,
Sum(conjuntos.n_uhs) AS uh,
programas.id AS programa,
conjuntos.name
FROM
conjuntos
Inner Join conjuntos_programas ON conjuntos_programas.conjunto_id = conjuntos.id
Inner Join programas ON programas.id = conjuntos_programas.programa_id
Inner Join cidades ON conjuntos.cidade_id = cidades.id
WHERE
conjuntos.situation_id =  2
GROUP BY
conjuntos.cidade_id
ORDER BY
municipio ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got duplicate rows, you can check this by removing the `group by` and the `SUM(...` from your query.
Change the query as follows and tell me if that fixes to problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  cidades.id AS id,
  cidades.name AS municipio,
  SUM(conjuntos.n_uhs) AS uh,
  programas.id AS programa,
  conjuntos.name
FROM conjuntos
INNER JOIN conjuntos_programas ON conjuntos_programas.conjunto_id = conjuntos.id
INNER JOIN programas ON programas.id = conjuntos_programas.programa_id
INNER JOIN cidades ON conjuntos.cidade_id = cidades.id
WHERE conjuntos.situation_id =  2
GROUP BY conjuntos.cidade_id
ORDER BY municipio ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a one to many relationship between two or more of your tables to be doing this.  Try doing a `SELECT *` and start debugging your query to see where it is duplicating the rows.